# String Builder Class in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

SqlDataReader myreader;
                            myreader = cmmd.ExecuteReader();

```
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        sb.Append("<b>Vaccine</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b> Vaccination Date</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b> Vaccination Due Date</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b> Incomplete Vaccination </b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Dose No.</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b> Remarks </b><br/><br/>");
                        while (myreader.Read())
                            {
                                    sb.Append(myreader["VaccineID"]);
                                    sb.Append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                                    sb.Append(myreader["DateOFVaccine"]);
                                    sb.Append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                                    sb.Append(myreader["NextVaccinationDueDate"]);
                                    sb.Append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                                    sb.Append(myreader["AnyIncompleteImmunization"]);
                                    sb.Append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                                    sb.Append(myreader["DoseNumber"]);
                                    sb.Append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
                                    sb.Append(myreader["Remark1"]);
                                    sb.Append("<br/>");
                            }
                        lblDisplayDetails.Text = sb.ToString();
                        myreader.Close();
```

WHAT EXACTLY I WANT IS TO RETRIEVE DATA(may be from separate table) AND THEN DISPLAY THEM PUTTING SOME STYLE(font,color etc).

Is retrieving from multiple table is possible in gridview ? I could use the DataReader, but how to display them in style(font,color etc) ?
Regards
Indranil

Comment: Yuk. I really hope you're not developing that for the NHS!

Comment: i think this will work for sure 
or 
you can care one div element 
and do divId.innerhtml = sb.ToString();

Comment: This code is honestly giving me the creeps right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.aspx) control, and since your string contains html tags, you'll need to set the control's `Mode` to `PassThrough`

**This is a very dangerous thing to do**, because if a hacker or even a digruntled user somehow gets the string `<script>alert('haha i hacked your site')</script>` into any of your database cells, such as "Remark1", then you've just fallen victim to an [XSS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

You'll need to call Server.HtmlEncode on all of your myreader fields:

```
sb.Append(Server.HtmlEncode(myreader["Remark1"]));
```

like this page recommends: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2a4yykt.aspx

Comment: thanks for the accept, but please consider researching gridview & repeater. You're not in PHP-land any more!

Answer (score 13):

2 words!

```
GridView
```

&

```
Repeater
```

Comment: That is definitely the way to go. Programmers are awesome at "i know you asked for X, but really, you need to use Z"